# List files and folders recursively with numbering

Tags: excel, vba, tree, directory

Example of folder structure with files:

- folder 1

  - subfolder 1

    - file 1
    - file 2
  - subfolder 2

    - file 3
- folder 2

  - file 4

I want this structure translated to a spreadsheet as follows:

`column 1    column 2 
1            folder 1
1.1          subfolder 1
1.1.1        file 1
1.1.2        file 2
1.2          subfolder 1
1.2.1        file 3
2            folder 2
2.1          file 4`

How can I do this the best? I have tried VBA macros. I did manage to list all files and folders. But the numbering is not succeeding. Please note, the depth of subfolders is not limited to this example. In theory the numbering can go further than 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 etc.

```
Sub FolderNames()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object, j As Long, folder1 As Object
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the folder"
    .Show
End With
On Error Resume Next
xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
'Application.Workbooks.Add
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
xWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = xPath
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("Level", "Name")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder1 = fso.getFolder(xPath)
getSubFolder folder1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object)
Dim xFolderName As String
Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
Dim xFolder As Object
Dim xSubFolder As Object
Dim xFile As Object
Dim rowIndex As Long
Dim filecounter As Integer
Dim foldercounter As Integer
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim subfld As Object
Dim xRow As Long
foldercounter = 1

For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
subcount = subcount + 1
    filecounter = 1
    xFolderName = SubFolder.Path
    Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.getFolder(xFolderName)
    xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

    Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(foldercounter, filecounter, SubFolder.Name)

    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(foldercounter, filecounter, xFile.Name)
        filecounter = filecounter + 1
    Next xFile

    foldercounter = foldercounter + 1
Next SubFolder

For Each subfld In prntfld.SubFolders
    getSubFolder subfld
Next subfld

End Sub
```

Comment: Please describe HOW the numbering is not succeeding. Give an example of what you get and what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below should work, which takes your general concepts but restructures them.  I added another parameter, prntLevel, to getSubFolder, which is a string that gets prefixed to the index of the subfolder or file.  It becomes a longer and longer sequence of numbers as the procedure recurses back through itself as it gets deeper into the folder structure.

Also, to make it easy to understand, each subfolder gets an index of 0 to distinguish it from files contained with in.  Otherwise for instance 1.1 can be either the first file or the first subfolder which starts to become non-obvious in my opinion as your tree gets deeper.

```
Sub FolderNames()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim xPath As String
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim fso As Object, j As Long, folder1 As Object
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Choose the folder"
        .Show
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    'Application.Workbooks.Add
    Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
    xWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = xPath
    xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array("Level", "Name")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder1 = fso.getFolder(xPath)
    getSubFolder folder1, ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object, prntLevel As String)
    Dim xFolderName As String
    Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xSubFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim filecounter As Integer
    Dim foldercounter As Integer
    Dim SubFolder As Object
    Dim subfld As Object
    Dim xRow As Long
    foldercounter = 1
    For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
        subcount = subcount + 1
        filecounter = 0
        xFolderName = SubFolder.Path
        Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.getFolder(xFolderName)
        xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
        Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(prntLevel & foldercounter & "." & filecounter, SubFolder.Name)
        getSubFolder SubFolder, prntLevel & foldercounter & "."
        For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
            filecounter = filecounter + 1
            xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
            Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(prntLevel & foldercounter & "." & filecounter, xFile.Name)
        Next xFile
        foldercounter = foldercounter + 1
    Next SubFolder
End Sub
```